# Accessibility of a Class

Tags: class, object, design-patterns, architecture

I want to design a solution, but facing a problem because of limited knowledge of OOPs concept. My requirement is as follows

Assume I have 4 classes
Class A
Class B
Class C
Class D

I want object of class D can only be allowed to create, or class can only be accessible in Class C. Same Class C object and class itself can be allowed access and created in Class B. Class D should not have access to class B.
Same Class A should not have access to C, D. It only have access to B, and it can create object of B.

How we can implement with best possible architecture/design pattern in C#.

With Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: [Ensure that only class A can call class B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028578/ensure-that-only-class-a-can-call-class-b)

After you have read that, you will know you have to use a combination of package and private classes.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution of your problem can be solved by the use of private inner classes.
make `class D` class inner to `class C` and `class C` inner to `class B` and so on.

but remember the use of inner classes is highly deprecated.

implementing this in C#, I leave up to you.